# How to get class name of listener using event type passed in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, event-listener

I have one event named "Search" and listener class named as "TestDataSend" and would like to call listen like

Event called like

```
$eventData = [
    "type_id" => $id,
     "event_type" => 'search_event',
];
event(new SearchEvent($eventData));
```

so I would like to

```
(new $listener)->handle($event);
```

so how can I get the class name of listener based on event type?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I want to call listener manually using listener class so how to call it dynamically?

Comment: are you looking `Event::dispatch('event.name', $data);` ?

Comment: What is event name here? @AbdullaNilam

Comment: your `SearchEvent`

Comment: so can I call like Event::dispatch('search_event', $data); ?

Comment: Is `$listener` that event object you wish to get it's class for?

Comment: $listener should be the class name of listener class which I want to get @nice_dev

Comment: @BhumiShah Is this useful? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php

Comment: nope @nice_dev I am writing custom command and want to call listener from that

Comment: @BhumiShah Ok, can you break down your question to simple class and method calls, if you don't mind? I presume, to solve your current query, I would have to be aware of Laravel events and their flow.

Comment: @nice_dev my question is, to call listener dynamically using command and in command, I will pass event data

Comment: @BhumiShah Ok, but what is the driver code for `$listener`? How is this variable getting the value or how will it be called?

Comment: @nice_dev I have command like this from where I am calling listener php artisan worker:command "{\"type_id\":\"1\",\"event_type\":\"search_event\"}"